# Best performance when creating custom directive when looping in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The following code is being used 10 times throughout my app.

I'd thought I would refactor it to a custom directive:

```
<div class="names-container">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="name in vm.namesCollection">
            <span>{{ ::name.first  }}</span>
            <span>{{ ::name.second  }}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I am not sure which implementation would be the best in terms of performance:

1. a directive where the template is defined with templateUrl
2. a directive where the template is defined using compile function (compile: function(element, attrs, transcludeFn)....)
3. a directive where the template is defined using link function
4. raw HTML, i.e - leave it as it is

** I Intentionally left 'ng-include' out of the list as it is significantly slower than other options.

I run across [ng-include vs static-include](https://jsperf.com/ng-include-vs-static-include/5), but it doesn't show the compile function test (or am I missing it?)

And another small thing related - should I put the complete HTML in the directive's HTML or just the 'li' element ?

Comment: I see nothing here that explicitly mandates a directive, but I *do* see a simple component here.

Comment: consider this code snippet to appear 10 times throught the app

Comment: How large of a list comes in there? It makes quite a difference!

Comment: Also,  are those list's static, or do they need to be monitored for changes?

Comment: the list is ~30 items length. No monitor is needed (notice the one time binding mark in the example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development in ui is not only coding its also about designing or user interface .If your design for ng-repeat gets changed then 4th option is best but if design is common you can use your own custom  directive .You use templateUrl only if your template grows more than expected size . Compile gives you more control over link function choose according to your logic requirements .

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/28/compile-pre-and-post-linking-in-angularjs.aspx

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1020844/Compile-Pre-Post-Options-in-AngularJS

Now, for your last question you can add the whole html if you want to have same design or add only li to get some control over design.

Personal recommendation , use Components available in new versions of angularjs

Comment: thank you, but you didn't quite answer my question - which way of implementing a custom directive is the optimal for using it with ng-repeat?

Comment: All of them are optimal Its completely depends on your need well a 2. directive where the template is defined using compile function (compile: function(element, attrs, transcludeFn)....) is best as its gives you complete control .